# Rails GA Core Reporting API V4 orderBys not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics

I am trying to fetch most used site internal search keyword from GA using Core Reporting API V4.
Here's my code.

```
require "google/apis/analyticsreporting_v4"

class GoogleAPI

  def auth
    Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
      json_key_io: File.open(ENV['GOOGLE_AUTH_KEY_FILE']),
      scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
    )
  end

  def popular_keywords
    service = Google::Apis::AnalyticsreportingV4::AnalyticsReportingService.new
    service.authorization = auth

    query = {
      view_id: ENV['POPULAR_KEYWORDS_GA_VIEW'],
      dimensions: [{name: 'ga:searchKeyword'}],
      metrics: [{expression: 'ga:searchUniques'}],
      page_size: 1000,
      orderBys: [{fieldName: 'ga:searchUniques', orderType: 'VALUE', sortOrder: 'DESCENDING'}],
      date_ranges: [{start_date: '30daysAgo', end_date: 'today'}]
    }

    request = Google::Apis::AnalyticsreportingV4::GetReportsRequest.new
    request.report_requests = [query]

    reports = service.batch_get_reports request

    p reports.to_h

    []
  rescue => e
    []
  end

end
```

All works as expected, it fetches keywords as dimensions and used numbers as metrics.
But orderBys not applied.  I am expecting to order by `ga:searchUniques` at descending order.
It seems it's being ordered by `ga:searchKeyword` (dimension) at ascending order.

Anyone please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got an answer.
The line `orderBys: [{fieldName: 'ga:searchUniques', orderType: 'VALUE', sortOrder: 'DESCENDING'}]` should be replaced with `order_bys: [{field_name: 'ga:searchUniques', sort_order: 'DESCENDING'}]`